# Function<Unit> does not have invoke method?

Tags: kotlin

I want to use an anonymous function with no argument and without return type so I use `Function<Unit>` as type. When I want to call invoke() on it, the compiler says that the function cannot be invoked as a function and that the function invoke is not found. It works with `Function1<Unit, Unit>`.

I use kotlin plugin 1.2.41.

Is it normal ?

Comment: [Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-function.html) doesn't show any invoke() method, so yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is rather `Function0<Unit>` then.

Note that all functions `Function0`, `Function1`, ... `FunctionN` extend from `Function`.